# How to download Spacy language model on Bluemix

Tags: python, ibm-cloud, spacy

I have a python program I am pushing to bluemix.  The program uses spacy.  I am not using any buildpack since bluemix doesn't require one for python.  I put spacy in my requirements.txt and do the push.  Spacy requires installing language models.  The command to install the english language model is the following:

python -m spacy.en.download all

How can I do this on bluemix?

https://spacy.io/docs/usage/

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that before you push to Bluemix you need to specify the data path to download SpaCy to within your project directory. Just create a folder in your project for the language model and put it in there.

According to your link, this can be done with the following command:

```
python -m spacy.en.download all --data-path /some/dir
```

Then just push your project to Bluemix like you would before.

Comment: Okay, but how do I get that command executed on bluemix?  And how could I just get it to work like normal and just install to the regular python install location like on a normal machine?

Comment: I see what you are saying.  I run the command with /some/dir that is in my directory that I am pushing and then the push will move it.  I would then have to point to that /some/dir path when I use spacy on bluemix.  I am guessing that the push to bluemix will fail because it will then be too big or take too long.  I am already having that problem with this push.  I have set the timeout to the max.  The push loses connection if it takes longer than 15 minutes.  It would be much better to be able to somehow do the language model download directly on bluemix.